# Worker service stops working unexpectedly

Tags: c#, .net-core, service-worker, worker

I have .NET Core 3+ worker service that checks "some stuff" every 10 seconds. At one point, it "randomly" stopped doing that and I am not sure why. So far it happened twice and there are no exception logs or anything like it, so I can only assume that I should add a `try-catch` inside ExecuteAsync, but my question is: Are there any known issues that could cause a similar behavior where the worker just stops executing?

And yes, there was no cancellation requested (else, I suppose it would log the message "Sender is stopping").

```cs
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Sender is starting");
        stoppingToken.Register(() => _logger.LogInformation("Sender is stopping"));

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);

            _logger.LogDebug("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

            if (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                await SendPendingMessages();
        }
    }

    private async Task SendPendingMessages()
    {
        var list = ...

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            try
            {
                // Do stuff as expected
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So far it happened twice and there are no exception logs or anything like it, so I can only assume that I should add a try-catch inside ExecuteAsync, but my question is: Are there any known issues that could cause a similar behavior where the worker just stops executing?

It definitely sounds like an exception to me. By default, [the `BackgroundService` implementation will *ignore* any exceptions thrown from `ExecuteAsync`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/05/backgroundservice-gotcha-silent-failure.html). If an exception is raised from `ExecuteAsync`, it is ignored and the service just stops running.

I always recommend a top-level `try`/`catch` with logging, so that you're at least aware that this happens:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
  _logger.LogInformation("Sender is starting");
  try
  {
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
      await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
      _logger.LogDebug("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
      if (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        await SendPendingMessages();
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) when (stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    _logger.LogInformation("Sender is stopping");
  }
  catch (Exception ex) when (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    _logger.LogError(ex, "Sender had error");
  }
}
```

On a related note, if this is what you would consider a "critical" background service, then you would also want to [stop the application host when this service stops](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/06/backgroundservice-gotcha-application-lifetime.html):

```
private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _hostApplicationLifetime;

public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime)
{
  _logger = logger;
  _hostApplicationLifetime = hostApplicationLifetime;
}

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
  _logger.LogInformation("Sender is starting");
  try
  {
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
      await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
      _logger.LogDebug("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
      if (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        await SendPendingMessages();
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex) when (stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    _logger.LogInformation("Sender is stopping");
  }
  catch (Exception ex) when (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
  {
    _logger.LogError(ex, "Sender had error");
  }
  finally
  {
    _hostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that the line

```
await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
```

will throw OperationCancelledException when you trigger your cancellation token, it is unhandled.

Also make sure the `LogError()` `LogDebug()` have a catch all try block and cannot throw themselves, that would also break your code.

Can't see anything else that's problematic.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.thecodebuzz.com/waiting-for-host-disposed-ensure-ihost-instances-wrapped-in-using-blocks/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fcLZ.png)

UseConsoleLifetime() helps: example below

```
return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
            {

                services.AddHttpClient();

            }).UseConsoleLifetime();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).