# Worker Service mysteriously stops doing work

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, worker

My good ladies and gentlemen, I recently had my first go at Worker services in .Net Core 3.1, and only the second go at Windows services in general (first one was made in .Net Framework and works fine to this day). If anyone could maybe shed some light at what I'm missing in the example that I will provide that would be great.

So, to keep it simple, my problem is this:
My supposed long (forever) running Worker service unexpectedly stops doing work at an arbitrary time of day, but still is shown as "Running" in service manager (that's probably how Windows deals with services). It doesn't necessarily have to be every day, but it stops doing work every now and then until I manually stop it and then restart it in Service Manager.

I have also [stumbled upon this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62551007/worker-service-stops-working-unexpectedly) which seemed to deal with my problem, but even after completely wrapping all of my service's code blocks in try-catchs, even on top-level, I still get nothing registered in my Log table, or even in the file I set up to write in if my DB connection fails. Service seems to just stop calling ExecuteAsync() method.

Ok here's how my code's logically structured, I have excluded implementation and I'm just showing what happens until DoWork is called:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public Worker(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {                      
        return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try //paranoid try-catch
                {
                    await DoWork();
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45), stoppingToken);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    await Log(e, customMessage: "Proccess failed at top level.");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await Log(e, customMessage: "Proccess failed at topmost level.");
        }

    }

    private async Task DoWork()
    {
        try
        {
            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await Log(e);
        }
    }

    public async Task Log(Exception e, string user = null, string emailID = null, string customMessage = null)
    {
        
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am not handling cancellation, as in the question I linked above. Now that I think about it maybe I should, and something is *inadvertently sending cancellation*? The reason I didn't is because I'm not sure what events exactly signal the cancellation. Only the manual stopping of service, or something else maybe? And if it is the cancellation that was sent that caused my service to stop doing work, shouldn't it also stop my service from running?

Btw I just tested cancellation on dummy service which implements my logic with `while(true)` and it catches the stopping exception, even though it's a bit awkward, as it catches it and logs it multiple times before stopping, so I presume it may not be the cancellation token that is causing my DoWork not to fire.

[image: Publish settings (I'd installed it on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard)]

Comment: Have you checked the improvements in [Stephen C.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62554317/982149) ? Considering the stoppingToken is one, but I am aiming specifically at the part, where he is referring to stopping the application host. And taking note of the token's state, when handling the excpetion.

Comment: Might be for example a deadlock. Then for windows your service is indeed still running, while actually it's stuck somewhere and not doing anything useful (and no exceptions).

Comment: What if your logging function fails? Is it writing to SQL or something? If there is a transient network error, or two SQL Deadlocks in a row, then it would stop

Comment: @Fildor Even though in my mind I did make a mistake and treated the hosted service as the application, I didn't think this would concern me, as I want my BackgroundService to never exit. But still, I think it would be logically correct to add implement that annex as well. I think Evk is more in line about what might be happening as my service is relying HEAVILY on asynchrony.

Comment: Yes, he definitely has a point there. That's also, why I didn't mark that question as duplicate.

Comment: @Evk I think you hit the spot. I'm not sure how it hadn't crossed my mind that it just might be a deadlock. I'll admit this is the first time I'm relying this heavily on asynchrony so I never had any major problems, so maybe that's why. What I'm doing is basically bombarding Exchange API with hundreds of mail fetch requests so there might be something there, even though I made sure I completely separate the async logic and objects and make it standalone for each call. Add to that the fact that this only happens once in a few days, I'm not sure how I'm gonna debug this.

Comment: @Milney I have a fallback that writes to file in that case

Comment: I'd start with ensuring you have timeouts on every such call. Because if you are sending some request via, say, TCP connection (and that is http, usually database, and many other calls) and have no timeout (0), and connection unexpectedly breaks - you'll wait for reply forever. So for any such operation there should be a reasonable timeout set (usually apis that work with databases, http calls etc all provide a way to set that). And if you use any kind of locks (`lock` etc, or async analogs) - then of course check them too.

Comment: How do you deploy service? As Windows Service or using IIS?

Comment: @Hostel Windows service

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Ok guys I'd fixed it.</strike> See comment below.

I'd **guessed** that what was causing deadlock was probably too many concurrent calls from different threads to database over the *same* connection.
Not that that I knew **that** would be the cause (*and I still don't know and can only guess why this happens so if someone can clarify why this happens and why don't the calls get queued please do*), but as I tried to fix it that seemed like a good starting point.

What I did was just limit possible concurrent calls to 1:

1. Instantiate SemaphoreSlim on a **class level**:
   `private static SemaphoreSlim Semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);`
2. Insert a `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` before **each** of my DB calls and its respective `SemaphoreSlim.Release` in a finally block after the call:

```
try
{
    await Semaphore.WaitAsync();
    var id = await sqlCommand.ExecuteScalarAsync().ToString();
}
finally
{
    Semaphore.Release();
}
```

I thought this would decrease the performance but to my pleasant surprise I felt no noticeable difference.

Also, I was tempted to set Semaphore's initial count to more than 1 thread but I figured if deadlock happens for many threads, then it *might* happen for 2-10 threads. Does anyone perhaps know anything more about this number? Is it processor related, SQL related, or perhaps C# related?

Comment: This ain't it chief. The service hanged again yesterday after 5 days of continuous work(the longest run yet). I guess waiting for SQL calls helped but I guess I will have to wait for calls to EWS (Exchange API) as well, as I'd read that EWS acts suspicious when it faces heavy parallelism. Will update this eventually.

Comment: You should probably move the `await Semaphore.WaitAsync();` outside the try/finally block. Otherwise a failure to acquire the semaphore could result to releasing a non-acquired semaphore, increasing inadvertently the maximum degree of parallelism.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I think I get what you're saying. I thought I saw it used in try block in Microsoft docs but now on the second glance, MS docs also has it above try block. Thanks for the tip, makes sense, even though so far my log doesn't show signs of it happening.

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented a dispose method to close the database connection after finishing the DoWork method? I had a deadlock problem using worker service and realized the database connection wasn’t disposed. After implementing a dispose method, it works for me to solve the problem.

Comment: Hey, I don't explicitly call the dispose method on my SqlConnection instance, but it's wrapped inside a Using() statement. Shouldn't that be enough? 
And inside those Using statements I call a connection.Open(), without Closing it on the end of Using(), but I was thinking that shouldn't be an issue with connection pooling?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, and I don't know how or even if Manus's issue eventually resolved, but in my experience, exceptions in threads that aren't the main thread caused this problem for us in a Windows Service. And we didn't see this when running the same code as a Windows Forms. Try/catch wrapped around the main processing line does not catch them. We had to add it in the threaded method.