# Why does C# Worker Service always exit silently after running for exactly 1 hour?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, .net-6.0, worker-service

After many tests and implementing suggestions from different documents and blog posts about .NET Worker Service, I haven't been able to prevent it from stopping after running for what appears to be exactly 1 hour.

I can see that the worker finishes because it's generating logs and when that stops, the worker process in Task Manager is gone.

This Worker Service has been created with .NET 6, the output type is WinExe, and it's running in a Windows 11 machine.

What the worker does is to monitor the processes running on a machine and if a specific process stops it restarts it.

I guess the questions I have right now are:

- Why does it stop (apparently after 60 minutes)?
- What cancels it?
- How can it be prevented?
- Does it **have to be** turned into a Windows Service *necessarily* (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service) ?

  - If yes, why?

These are some of the resources I looked into which did not help fixing the issue yet:

[Worker service stops working unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62551007/worker-service-stops-working-unexpectedly)

https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/05/backgroundservice-gotcha-silent-failure.html

This is the ExecuteAsync method (with some redacting):

```cs
[SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    try
    {
        if (!_isInitialSetup)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Starting with account '{WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name}'");
        }
    }
    catch (SecurityException)
    {
        _logger.LogError("A security exception occurred when attempting to get the account name used by the worker service.");
    }

    RunSomeActionBeforeLongRunningTask();

    try
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => { ActionToRunInTheBackground(); });
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), stoppingToken);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Error in ExecuteAsync");
    }
    finally
    {
        // cleanup...;
    }
}
```

This is part of the `.csproj` file where the output type is specified:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
      <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
      <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
      <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
      <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
      <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
      <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
      <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
      <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
      <BuiltInComInteropSupport>true</BuiltInComInteropSupport>
```

This is pretty much all there is to this application. It runs pretty well until it silently exits.

P.S.: The work around I'm using right now is to make the worker restart itself after the process has been running for about 50 minutes. This has been working, but I would really like to understand why it exits.

Also, I'm kind of willing to switch to a Windows Service, but I haven't found any explanation on why that would be required. Although, I'm also interested in replacing the Wix installer with MSIX, but I read in the docs that the latter does not support Windows Services, so I would prefer keeping the service as a Console WinExe process.

Comment: What is the indication that it has exited after an hour?

Comment: @rfmodulator, I can see that the process is gone from Task Manager and it also stops generating the logs and running the background task. (Just edited the question, thanks).

Comment: Where I was going with that was sleep mode or something.... there's no telling what Microsoft screwed up this time. Are you able to confirm the same behavior on Windows 10? Maybe set an alarm and start watching the Task Manager at 55 minutes or so? `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException` might be useful if it's available.

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example. There's nothing in Windows, .NET, or the BCL that will cancel your background service after an hour. Are you running this as a Console app, in ASP.NET, or as a Win32 service?

Comment: @StephenCleary 
I've edited the question adding a little more context. It's basically a self-contained console app, but the output type is WinExe so there's no terminal. This behavior has been consistent on two different machines.

Comment: I strongly suspect the problem is in the redacted code, with a small possibility of a third party (e.g., antivirus). Again, Windows, .NET, and the BCL will not just terminate applications for no reason. So I expect that changing from a headless app to a Win32 service won't solve your problem.

Comment: The redacted code monitors running processes and restarts a specific process if it stops. Yes, very unlikely to be AV. I agree, I don't think the process would end for no reason, but I'm having a hard time figuring out what that reason is. I'm trying to catch any exceptions but nothing so far (no unhandled exceptions in Event Viewer either). Sometime ago, in another company, I had seen a similar behavior but in a Linux container with .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: @StephenCleary, changing it to a Windows Service did in fact solve the problem. No changes in the redacted code, I simply added the NuGet reference to make it run as a Windows Service and boom, it simply works.
Still, I totally don't know what is terminating it when running as a headless process.